# Missing in Weekly Reputation League

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I have been active on WPSE from the past week and gained 200+ rep this week until now. It does show here: [Weekly Reps](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) but not here: [Weekly Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/42/week/wordpress)

Can I assume this as a bug or being a new user I am not able to get into the reputation league?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation leagues only track those with 200+ reputation and you only reached that point today (yesterday you had a rep of 198 so you just missed out). You should see yourself in the league tomorrow after it updates.

The site wide reputation leagues only update once a day unlike the weekly reps page which is part of the local site and is closer to real time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It does show me now :)